# Places API locatiobias is ignored

Tags: google-places-api

When searching for a specific place in the Google Places API I found out that Google delivers results far away from the restriction I sent with.

For example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?key=<mykey>&inputtype=textquery&input=<PlaceQuery>&fields=name,geometry&locationbias=circle:200@<lat>,<lng>
```

In this query above I tried to find a place in a specific circle (200 metres) around a point lat lng. (Removed for this post)

Google does it's work but when I enter a place to search for which is definitely not in the region I specified it still finds the place.

Did I misunderstood something with this type of search query? Or is it a mistake at googles end?

Comment: Location bias doesn't mean a strict filter. Google can return results from outside of specified area if there are no prominent results inside.